# Getting data from parent app when Watch App loads for the first time

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

Our watch app is a companion to our iOS app, so when you open a specific screen on the iOS app it will send the data to the watch app. For this I am using `WCSession`. But, there is a situation where this doesn't work:

- iOS app screen opened but Watch App not open yet, so data isn't sent.

Basically when the watch app opens I need to check and see if there is data from the iOS app.

I have tried:

```
WCSession* session = [WCSession defaultSession];
[session updateApplicationContext:applicationDict error:nil];
```

But this method doesn't seem to have the data waiting on my Watch App even when using the correct delegate method as described in the docs.